# Hide label for input without attribute "required" (float label)

Tags: html, css, label, floating

I have this code:

```
<span class="field">
<input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" required />
<label for="first-name">First Name</label>
</span>

<span class="field">
<input type="text" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" />
<label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
</span>
```

Label for the second input ("Last Name") is visible from the beginning and not only on focus like the "First Name" label. The difference between two inputs is only in attribute "required" which I don't need for the "Last Name" field.

How to make label for input without attribute "required" hidden? I need it to be shown only on focus with the transition effect. The same like this work for "First Name" field.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmitriy_kalmykov/68jmbquy

Answer (score 1):

You could use the adjacent sibling selector. Add the following code to your CSS file.

```
input[required] + label {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using required for the last-name field too, but overwriting the required attribute for the last-name input by javascript while submiting the form.

`document.getElementById("last-name").required = false;`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 9 month ago, but this can help somebody in future. 
I guess you can't submit the form because all fields with float labels should be with the required attribute.If you leave a field empty, the form won't submit. If you remove the attribute, the label is visible and you can submit the form, but the idea of floating labels is ruined.

If I am correct, then try this code:

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

$('#sub-btn').click(function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.field').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
        $(this).removeAttr("required");
  });
  return isValid;
});
});
```

It works for me. You should **set the submit button with** **id="sub-btn"** so when you click it, it will clean the required properties.

Comment: forgot to mention that in my case, the input has class="field"